# Как правильно вставлять в предложения диалог?

Tags: синтаксис

Есть такое предложение

> Как сделать так, чтобы когда на всех вопросах стояло правильно, то высвечивалась информация в табло со словами - "вы выиграли".

Я его отредактировал на подобном сайте. Насколько я помню из школьного курса, я все сделал правильно, но почему-то засомневался. Тут просто вмешался мой опыт, которому кажется, что что-то не так. Помогите разрешить спор между моим опытом и знаниями.

В общем вопрос прост, какие ошибки в предложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

**Как сделать так, чтобы при правильных ответах на все вопросы на табло высвечивалась информация  со словами  "вы выиграли"?**

Здесь "вы выиграли" — дословное высказывание в роли несогласованного определения.

Comment: Опыт был прав)))))  Благодарю...

Comment: Нужно заметить, что  нет здесь никакого диалога, упомянутого в вопросе.

Comment: На табло должно быть: "Вы выиграли" — с прописной, и скорее всего - с воскл. знаком.

Comment: Информация со словами "вы выиграли" => Смысл сказанного: некое информационное сообщение,  в которое включены слова "вы выиграли". Так ли это?  Верится с трудом. Скорее  всего, кроме слов  "Вы выиграли!" там больше ничего не должно быть.